Name expected issue - convert Json to class
I am trying to convert Json string into instance of a class.
There is 'Name expected' error as below image.
I could not find any solution from Googling.

I added below dependency into build.gradle(app)
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7")

Definition of data class is as below.
data class Person(val id: Int, val email: String, val first_name: String, val last_name: String, val avatar: String)
data class Page(val page: Int, val per_page: Int, val total: Int, val total_pages: Int, val data: List<Person>)

Please let me know what I missed.
Hope you have a great day.

I found the solution.
Page::class.java should be used instead of Page.class.
